Best way to generate a variable clean DC current
On one end I have an amArduino or other microcontroller. On the other end I have a small electromagnet coil with about 20 turns of 1 inch diameter. I need to drive this coil with some precision (say 5-8 bits) in both positive and negative directions (DC), to about -3 to 3 A.
I first tried using a brushed motor driver with a large capacitor to smooth out the current which gave me fine control and steady current, but the noise ripples are causing issues.
Any ideas for how to do this cleanly (and hopefully easily/maximizing off-the-shelf components)? Or am I tackling an especially difficult project?

One or the other end of what?

I am trying to come up with a circuit that can sit in between the arduino and the coil, to give me fine control over the current without noise

A bit of advice. If at all possible, use more turns on your electromagnet. Otherwise an efficient solution will be rather difficult.

Are you asking about how to implement an H Bridge? there are a ton of tutorials and explanations about that on here and elsewhere. you can use PWM to control how much current you are sending and measure the current with a current sense resistor going back to the uC to get the precision you need

@MathKeepsMeBusy I wish I could add more turns to the coil, but this is a limitation of the system.

@Hatman I understand h-bridges and pwm mosfet control, but in my experience those tend to pass along a bunch of the pwm noise. I need as clean of a dc signal as possible. I was wondering if there was a better approach (linear regulator, dc-dc converter, switched capacitor converter, digital potentiometer, high current biased op amp)

@user1402154 I think an LC filter on your output lines would solve the problem

The voltage drop across 20 turns of coil will be so small, that you will waste nearly all of your power on the drive circuitry. You will be lucky to get 5% efficiency. You will want to step down the voltage to as low as you can get.

@MathKeepsMeBusy whats a good way to step down dc-dc without adding more noise to the system?

What is the real problem you are trying to solve? You haven't told us what that is. Let's call it X. You think the solution is Y, so you ask how to implement Y. This is what is known as an XY problem. Instead of focusing on how to implement your proposed solution, ask about your real, concrete problem.

@MathKeepsMeBusy The real problem I am trying to solve is to sweep a magnetic field in a small volume at ultra-high temperature. To do that I developed some high temp coils, but I am struggling a bit on how to power them. I was able to use an off the shelf brushed motor driver, plus like a 2 farad Resistor/Capacitor circuit. This gives pretty steady current at whatever level I request, but it comes with heavy ripple at some currents.

@user1402154 Can you explain why you cannot purchase or make a different coil with more turns? Can you explain why switching noise would be a problem? Can you explain why the field needs to be reversible? (i.e. current flowing in either/both directions)

@MathKeepsMeBusy I can explain the coil parameters but NDA starts to get tricky? The switching noise is a problem because Im also using a lock-in system to listen to a signal at 1000 hz, which the noise is messing with.

If the switching noise were to be, at say 300 kHz, would that be a problem?

@MathKeepsMeBusy as long as there isnt any unintended noise at lower frequencies it should be ok. are you familiar with any off the shelf bipolar 300khz switching dc sources?

A Peltier TEC controller fits the bill. Just modulate the "temperature" feedback signal.

This answer will not give a specific solution, but will a) address a fundamental problem you are facing, and b) provide an overview of possible solutions. Once you have more information, it may prompt you to ask more specific questions about possible solutions. (These more specific questions should be asked separately, not as additions to this questions).
The fundamental problem you face is that a coil of 20 turns will have a very low DC resistance - somewhere in the milliohms or even fractions of milliohms. What that means practically will depend upon the type of current source you are looking at.
The simplest way to provide a variable -3 A to 3 A current source is with a 4 quadrant linear power supply. There are off the shelf power supplies that will provide 4 quadrant operation up to 3 A. These tend to run in the hundreds of dollars, and generally are controlled by knobs mounted on the case, rather than via an external signal.
Next up would be a 4 quadrant linear power supply that is designed for your particular application. Such a power supply could be controlled by an external signal, such as a voltage, or an externally control digital potentiometer. Such a power supply could easily be built for less than $100 in parts, but there is the expenses of design and build and testing. One of the issues you would face with such a power supply is heat. If your variable supply is powered by, say a constant 5 V supply, it must be able to dissipate at least 15 watts of heat -- the 5 volts times the 3 amps. For most ICs and/or power transistors, this will require significant heat sinking. A power resistor could be added to reduce the heating of the IC and/or power transistors. At 1.5 ohm resistor could be used to offload much of that 15 watts. This power resistor will itself need heat-sinking, and should be rated for at least 30 watts dissipation.
An alternative to linear power supplies, which necessarily will dissipate much more power than they deliver to your coil is switching regulators. To get 4 quadrant operation, a 4 switch bridge would be an appropriate choice. However, rather than using the output of such a regulator, there should be your load coil and a current limiting inductor within the bridge, like so.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Again, you are faced with the choice of design/build/test vs purchasing a more general device.
There are two sorts of commercial switching devices that might provide much of the functionality ready made. One is motor drivers, which tend to be quite noisy electrically. The other is 4 quadrant class D audio amplifiers, which we will consider next.
The switching frequency of 4 quadrant class D audio amplifiers can often be very high, say 200 kHz up to 1.5 MHz. This feature will be very useful for filtering out noise. However the audio amplifier needs to be one with DC coupling only! With DC coupling, the input voltage can be used to control pulse width modulation and consequently the current to the electromagnet coil. Another property the class D amplifier must possess is the ability to drive inductive loads. We use an inductor within the bridge to limit the current. (As opposed the linear regulator example, where we use a resistor or transistor(s) to limit the current). A third requirement of the class D amplifier is that it does not have it's own low pass filters for the output (or that these low pass filters can be disabled). This is necessary so that the current is limited by the inductor we add to the load. If low pass filters are present, they will defeat the purpose of the current limiting inductor.
Most commercial class D audio amplifiers are rated to handle either 4 ohm or 8 ohm loads. To get 3 amps into a 4 ohm load requires an amplifier capable of outputting 334 = 36 watts. (You would actually need a bit more power capability, but because we are using inductive loads, the actual power will be much lower). Getting 4 ohms of impedance out of an inductor operating at, say 250 kHz, requires an approximately 2.6 uH inductor. An inductor of a nearby size capable of handling 3 amps is easily obtainable.
There are commercially available boards that come close to what you want, for well under $100. For example, there are boards based upon TI's TPA3118, such as this one available on Amazon for less than $10. I cannot vouch for the quality of this product, as it does not come from a electronics supplier that I trust. Nor can I guarantee that it can operate using only an inductive load. It does appear to have low pass filters for the output, but these can be disabled by desoldering the two electrolytic capacitors. The inductors appear to be larger than needed, so if you are operating with a low voltage supply, you might want to remove them and use a single, say 3.3 uH, 3 amp inductor in their place. If you use a high enough supply voltage, replacing these inductors may not be needed. I am not endorsing this as a solution, however, your project were my project, I would definitely look at hacking this board (in the manner described) as a possible solution, costing relatively little, and requiring only minor modifications. I would also look at similar boards. One important thing that will be missing from virtually any commercial board is a current sensing resistor and associated current sense amplifier. The sensed current will be needed to provide negative feedback so that the input signal controls the output current.
Note that if this board is a significant distance from the electromagnet coil, you will want to add a shunt capacitor (non-polarized) between the output terminals of the amplifier so that the high frequency ripple current is mostly confined to the board, rather than traveling up through the wires.
Again, this answer is not meant to be a definitive solution to your problem, but to give you a basis upon which you may ask more questions. (Again, these questions should be asked separately and should be self contained. This is not a "thread"-style forum.)

All you need is bipolar 3A at low voltage - literally a couple of volts. It’s a relatively trivial thing to make work. Get two 3V switching power supplies with 4A capacity, configure them for symmetric supply, add a MOSFET drain follower stage on a heatsink, control using an op-amp and analog control voltage. The output stage should be configured for class C to make life easy. With a short circuit load, you’ll be wasting 10W. Any desktop CPU cooler will deal with that in a small volume, and they can be as quiet as you want to pay for. D-S voltage across the mosfets is so low that you won’t exceed any SOA limits if you’d use 10A parts rated for 30W at least I think.
The circuit can be put together in an afternoon. Of course the op-amps controlling the mosfets will need +/-15V supply but that’s simple enough - use a decent DC/DC module running from 3V or 5V for that. Plenty of those around precisely for use with classic op-amps.
